# Configuring Firebase features in Pulumi

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

Can anyone point me to documentation on how to configure Firebase features in Pulumi. For example, Firebase Auth is disabled by default and I would like to enable auth with email/password and anonymous login

Comment: Sign-in providers can be enabled from within the Firebase console here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers

Comment: @frankvanpuffelen im trying to do this with pulumi. I don't want to have to manually enable things in the console every time I deploy new infrastructure

Comment: I'm not familiar with pulumi, but doubt there's anything specific that Firebase provides for it. There seems to be a package in pulumi to access Firebase projects through its REST API though: https://www.google.com/search?q=pulumi+firebase You'd have to look in/near that package for support for this REST API: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.defaultSupportedIdpConfigs